# Clientid sent to javascript function returns null when using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am trying to pass the clientid of a textbox into a javascript function.  For some reason when i use document.getElementById it returns a null.  Please Help

```
function incNumber(textId){

    var id = textId

    var test = document.getElementById(textId);

    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
    var res = isNaN(c)
    if (res) {
        c = 0;
    }
    else {
        c++;
    }  

    document.getElementById(textId).value = c;
}

<asp:TextBox ID="pointVal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Increase" ID="inc" OnClientClick="javascript:incNumber('<%= pointVal.ClientID %>'); return false;" />
```

Comment: It seems like the input's ID is set to `pointVal` and you're calling the function with `pointVal.ClientID`, if `pointVal.ClientID` is not equal to `pointVal`, you're not using the correct ID when you call `getElementById`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean.  The functions soul purpose is to increment a counter in the textbox.  When the button is pressed is should send that textbox ID.  I have the understanding that pointVal.ClientID would send the client side ID to the function.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `vb.net` but I think that the problem is that the ID you're passing to the `incNumber` JavaScript function is not the same as the one you're setting to the input. Try to use `ID="<%= pointVal.ClientID %>"` or call the JavaScript function using `incNumber('pointVal')`

Comment: textId is the id, $(textId) is not.

Comment: Sorry thats bad code.  The first getElementByID comes up null.  I'll edit it to look correct.